# Merge tags [viewpager] and [android-viewpager]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request

I propose we merge these two tags together.

All 227 of the questions tagged under [viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager) are also tagged under the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag (as seen by [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73753/posts-tagged-with-viewpager-but-not-android)).

---

## Before:

[viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager) **x 227**

[android-viewpager](/questions/tagged/android-viewpager) **x 334**

## After:

[android-viewpager](/questions/tagged/android-viewpager) **x 561**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed (posting this wiki answer to get the question off the unanswered page, please upvote).